# SqlException: Invalid object name 'Products'. when in Production mode but in Development working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
public ViewResult List(string category , int productPage = 1) => View(new ProductsListViewModel
{
    Products = repository.Products
                         .Where(p=> category == null || p.Category == category)
                         .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
                         .Skip((productPage - 1) * PageSize)
                         .Take(PageSize),
                PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
                {
                    CurrentPage = productPage,
                    ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                    TotalItems = category == null ? repository.Products.Count() : repository.Products.Where(e => e.Category == category).Count()
                },
                CurrentCategory = category
            });
```

This is a part where my error is showing up.

I did a migrations of this two classes.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;


namespace SportsStore.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order>Orders { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

And a second one is :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace SportsStore.Models
{
    public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public AppIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    }
}
```

Really I don't know what to do.

I want to host this project on Azure. It's part of the PRO MVC CORE 2 from Adam Freeman (I did everything the same as in the book ! ).

I googled this and I only find out this answer: "this object doesn't exist in your database".

Comment: Check the _Migrations table in your database to see if the migrations have been run

Comment: Ok i did it. Sorry for making this post. I deleted migrations which i did $ dotnet ef database update --context AppIdentityDbContext and $ dotnet ef database update --context ApplicationDbContext and i just update this migrations again and its work now

Comment: You learned how to debug the migration process a little bit. That's a good start :)

Comment: maybe you forgot to publish some dll files on server try rebuild and check if all libraries updates by checking their time and republish them